unique_ptr не понятен синтаксис
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct MyDeleter {
    void operator()(int* ptr) {
        std::cout << "Custom Deleter: Deleting pointer" << std::endl;
        delete ptr;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<int, MyDeleter> p1(new int(5), MyDeleter());
    return 0; // Custom Deleter will be called when p1 goes out of scope
}

std::unique_ptr<int, MyDeleter> p1(new int(5), MyDeleter());
что это за вызов функции? если знаете, подскажите, где синтаксис учить вообще. Заранее спасибо.

Это не вызов функции, это старый способ передачи аргументорв в конструктор объекта p1. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization

Да. теперь понятно.
